# Is it possible to copy all customer related data migrate to another magento 2 database?

Tags: magento2, customer, data-migration

> I want to know how I can copy only customer related data
>
> to another Magento 2 database

If it is possible then what are the tables that I can copy to 
the second DB

Magento ver 2.2.6

Comment: do you want customers data only from m1 to m2 or m2 to another version ?

Comment: i want customer data  copy   to my  Magento site  to another magento site 

--same version for magento

Comment: you can dump these tables to get all customers data . And you can also import these tables to another magento2 database to get all customer as well.

Comment: If you get your result .please accept my answer for others :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question, you want to copy the basic information of customers (with their addresses) from one Magento installation to another one.

To do this, you don't need to dig into the database tables.

Magento 2 provides a default feature of exporting and importing customers' data.

Just go to **System** ⇒ **Export** ⇒ **Export Settings** to see the export options. Here you can export **customers main file** (containing the basic info) and **customer addresses**. Check the checkboxes which fields you don't want in the exported file.

Similarly, go to **System** ⇒ **Import** ⇒ **Import Settings** to see the import options.

For more detailed tutorial, visit:

https://bsscommerce.com/blog/how-to-import-and-export-customer-data-in-magento-2/

or

https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/magento-2-export-import-customers.html

Comment: i just want to copy customer data to 

another magento site.....

Answer (score 3):

All Customer Data Including Logs In This Table :

```
customer_address_entity;
customer_address_entity_datetime;
customer_address_entity_decimal;
customer_address_entity_int;
customer_address_entity_text;
customer_address_entity_varchar;
customer_entity;
customer_entity_datetime;
customer_entity_decimal;
customer_entity_int;
customer_entity_text;
customer_entity_varchar;
```